# Is there any python code that breaks from infinite recursion

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to swap rows in case there is a presence of 0 as the pivot element(diagonal elements) in order to find the inverse, using the gauss elimination method. But for matrices with multiple zeroes, the code gives in for infinite recursion. Is there any possible way to break the loop if such a matrix is given as input? I am out of ideas.

```py
A = [
    [0, 5], 
    [0, 0]
]

import copy

def inverse(A):
    # appling operations on a copy of matrix A   
    A_id = copy.deepcopy(A)
    A_id = squaremat(A_id)
    return A_id


def squaremat(A_id):       
    for i in range(len(A_id)):          
        if len(A_id) != len(A_id[i]):
            # checks given matrix is a square matrix
            error = "Sorry Matrix not invertible"
            return error
            break
    return swap(A_id)


def swap(A_id):
    for j in range(len(A_id)):            
        if j != len(A_id)-1 and A_id[j][j] == 0:     
            Temp = A_id[j]  
            A_id[j] = A_id[j + 1]
            A_id[j + 1] = Temp  
        elif j == len(A_id) - 1 and A_id[j][j] == 0:
            Temp1 = A_id[0]
            A_id[0] = A_id[j]
            A_id[j] = Temp1
    for k in range(len(A_id)):
        if A_id[k][k] == 0:
            return swap(A_id)
    return A_id

inverse(A)
```

The result is a `RECURSION ERROR`.

Comment: This is called halting problem and has no solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: an eye-opening information. Thanks @Jafer Isbarov

Comment: Not related but the more Pythonic way of swapping values of two variables is `A_id[0], A_id[j] = A_id[j], A_id[0]`. There is no need to use a temporary variable and it can be done in just one step.

Comment: I didn't get your point Accadias, but thank you for editing the question.

Comment: Generally instead of trying to catch an exception, detect an infinite loop, detect a memory overflow, etc. you should fix your code instead and write proper checks before computation to prevent such a situation to occur in the first place. Or write code that handles the matrix differently.

Comment: but i just wanna return an error message if an infinite recursion is happening.

Comment: am i out of luck, do i need to think hard?

Comment: @Charles, in the `swap()` function there are two places where you are swapping the values of two variables using the method of storing the value of the 1st variable in a temporary variable, assign the value of the 2nd variable to the 1st, assign the value of the temporary variable to the 2nd. In Python, we just do `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: you can determine if a given matrix is [invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) or not by first calculating its determinant, if it is zero is not invertible

Comment: ‘but i just wanna return an error message if an infinite recursion is happening.’ — you get that for free, that’s what a `RecursionError` is.

Comment: Ha,Ha nice one, but is there a way to add the exception..

Comment: If you want to follow Copperfield's suggestion, you can check the determinant of the matrix using `np.linalg.det()`.